# mysqli: no error, but not doing what it should

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to change existing `mysql` code to `mysqli`. Despite following many online guides and spending about 7 hours on this, I cannot get it to work. My code is below (I'm trying to store functions in a single file) - any help appreciated.

**1st file:**

```
function db_query($query) {
    // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    $con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if ($con == false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return $con;

    // Query the database
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    return $result;
}
```

**2nd file:**

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO logs(`email`, `logged`, `ip`) VALUES('" . $user . "', '" . $logged . "', '" . $IP . "')");
if ($result == false) {
    echo "fault here";
    // Handle failure - log the error, notify administrator, etc.
} else {
    // We successfully inserted a row into the database
    echo "log added";
}
```

I've checked that all the variables contain the correct values, and I get the "log added" message onscreen, but nothing is actually added to the database.

Have I done something stupidly wrong?

Comment: I could be wrong here but it looks like `db_query ` has a double return. First it returns first `con` and 3 lines further it returns `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `db_query` function will never execute [`mysqli_query`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp), because there is a `return` statement that terminates its execution.

You should edit your **1st file** like this:

```
function db_query($query) {
    $result = null;
    $con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
    if ($con) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        mysqli_close($con);
    } else {
        $result = mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

*N.B.* Remember to close the connection to the database by using the [`mysqli_close`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_close.asp) function.

Comment: Which return statement? What does the return statement actually do? I don't know anything about mysqli and was using instructions from a site so would like to understand what actually is happening/not happening. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user3691363 you have a `return` before `mysqli_query`. The PHP `return` statement immediately terminates the execution of a function when it is called from within that function.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So is that the same as using the mysqli_close function?

Comment: I removed the return from the db connect function, changed the line in the db_query($query) function to      // Query the database
  return $con ? mysqli_query($con, $query) : mysqli_connect_error();           and now I get the 'log added' confirmation again but still not added the info to the database

Comment: @user3691363 no, `return` returns the result of a function to its caller, `mysqli_close` closes the connection to a database.

Comment: Opening and closing a connection for every single query is… rather expensive.